# Read only access to Neovis.js

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am a rookie both in Neo4j and javascript.

I found out that the javascript Neovis.js can be used with a Neo4j database to render a visualization for queries. This is an excellent tool to develop and embed web applications using Neo4j. However, I soon realized that this has the potential to screw up the entire database since those queries can both read and write the database.

How do we avoid writing into the database when using Neovis.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either don't allow any queries with the `CREATE`, `MERGE`, `SET` in your application to be executed or if you have an enterprise version create a read-only user.

Comment: Yes, I thought these are the only best options and especially the first one if we don't have the enterprise version.